# I am trying to doing login through google login but it is giving me this error

Tags: authentication

Can you tell why this is showing me error. I have inserted client id and client secret

response_type: code
state: 683073035
redirect_uri: https://specsright.com
prompt: select_account
client_id: 192942774024-go01de6cnff31s137i31sfse918qe637.apps.googleusercontent.com
access_type: online
scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid

Comment: It's too little information to be able to help you. What error do you get? What is returning the error — Google or your code? How do you call the authorization endpoint? Try adding a bit more relevant information and we will try to help you.

Comment: i installed the plugin named super socializer i created the project in google developer console and gave client id and client secret later it was showing error